# how to know the old value of an element onChange or onTrigger in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button :

```
<button id="btn1">55</button>
```

And so I change the button value to test2

```
$('#btn1').text("22");
```

I want to show a background-picture if the buttons oldValue greater then the newValue.

How can I get the old value from this button?

"I have over 100 buttons and they are changing dynamically."

**Update:** Isn't there an event that fires before it changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare it before changing value.

For example

```
$('#btn1').text(function (index, old) {
   if (parseInt(old) > 22) {
    //change background image
   }
   return "22";
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xyaWW/)

Answer (score 5):

You could use jQuery's [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) call and store it for retrieval as needed.

For instance, say you HTML is:

> HTML

```
<form action="#" method="GET">
    <input type="text" value="369" />
    <button id="btnID">420</button>
</form>
```

You could easily first gather the data needed and asign it to each element:

> Opening script

```
$("button") //  would simply grab all buttons, you can use whatever css selector
    .each(function(i) {
        $(this).data("prevVal", parseInt($(this).text()));
    });
```

You can then later check this value against a new value as needed:

```
... some change function
    $('#btn1').text("22");
    if ($('#btn1').data("prevVal") > 22) {
        //  do work
    }
    $('#btn1').data("prevVal", 22)
```

> **Just FYI**

If you were using inputs instead it would be easier:

```
$("input").each(function(i) { $(this).data("prevVal", parseInt($(this).val())) })
    .on("change", function(e) {
        var newVal = parseInt($(this).val());
        if ($(this).data("prevVal") > newVal) {
            //  do work
        };
        $(this).data("prevVal" newVal);
    });
```

Or if you wanted to maintain a list of values:

```
$("input").each(function(i) { 
        $(this).data("vals", new Array());
        $(this).data("vals").push(parseInt($(this).val()));
    })
    .on("change", function(e) {
        $(this).data("vals").push(parseInt($(this).val()));
        var vals = $(this).data("vals");
        if (vals[vals.length-1] > vals[vals.length-2]) {
            //  do work
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Spyk3hh, I will test it now

Answer (score 1):

Unless you preserve it before the change you cannot get the old value. The change event is fired after the value has been changed already.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you want the old value.. but if it while changing the text then use the function to change the text.

```
$('#btn1').text(function (index, oldvalue) {
   console.log(oldvalue);
   return "test2";
});
```

Comment: I cant do that, because the buttons are getting changed dynamically

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery.data() to store data associated with the specified element and you will be able to get it just by accessing the same element.

Here's the [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to show you how to use jQuery.data();

Here's the code using a more convenient .data() [link](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Set

```
$("#btn1").data("oldVal",  $("#btn1").html());
```

Get

```
$("#btn1").data("oldVal");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZhEr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button id="btn1">test1</button>

    ​$(document).ready(function(){
        var i=1;
        $('#btn1').click(function(){
        $(this).data('old', $.trim($(this).text())).text('btn'+(++i));
            alert( $(this).data('old'));
        });
    });​
```

for [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/8KLxZ/)